# Delegate not getting set from a class

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

> TableViewRowProtocol

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol TableViewRowProtocol <NSObject>

-(void) addRow;

@end
```

Created  a delegate in class HeaderCell and call protocol method from the same

> HeaderCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewRowProtocol.h"

@interface HeaderCell : UITableViewCell<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* header;

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<TableViewRowProtocol> rowdelegate;

-(IBAction)add:(id)sender;
@end
```

> HeaderCell.m

```
#import "HeaderCell.h"
#import "MembershipsView.h"

@implementation HeaderCell
@synthesize header,rowdelegate;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
      if (self) {
          // Initialization code
      }
      return self;
  }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
      [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

      // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  -(IBAction)add:(id)sender
   {
       [rowdelegate addRow];
   }
@end
```

Then I created an Object of class `HeaderCell` in class `MembershipsView` and set `rowdelegate` as self, since method `addrow` in protocol is implemented in the same class

> MembershipsView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DoctorService.h"
#import "DEcell.h"
#import "HeaderCell.h"


@interface MembershipsView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,TableViewRowProtocol>

{
    NSMutableArray* memberships;

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int edit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView* membershipsTable;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* DoctorMembershipsDTO;
@property (nonatomic,strong) HeaderCell* ObjHeaderCell;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int selectedDoctorId;

-(void)whenViewLoaded;

@end
```

> MembershipsView.m

```
#import "MembershipsView.h"

@implementation MembershipsView
@synthesize selectedDoctorId,DoctorMembershipsDTO,edit,ObjHeaderCell;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MembershipsView" owner:self options:Nil] lastObject];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)whenViewLoaded
{
    DoctorMembershipsDTO=[[NSString alloc]init];
    memberships=[[DoctorService sharedInstance] getMembershipsByDoctorId:selectedDoctorId];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return memberships.count+1;

}


-(void)addRow
{
    UIAlertView* addMembership = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add Membership"` `message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];

   addMembership.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [addMembership textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
    [addMembership show];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(edit == 1)
    {
        if (0 == indexPath.row)
        {

            static NSString *cellId = @"HeaderCell";

            ObjHeaderCell = (HeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

            ObjHeaderCell.rowdelegate=self;
            if (ObjHeaderCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderCell"   owner:self options:nil];
                `ObjHeaderCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            ObjHeaderCell.header.text = @"Memberships";
            return ObjHeaderCell;
        }
        static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";

        DEcell *cell = (DEcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DEcell"   owner:self options:nil];
            `cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        DoctorMembershipsDTO = [memberships objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

        cell.labelText.text = DoctorMembershipsDTO;
        return cell;

    }
    else
    {
        static NSString* CellId= @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId] ;

        }

        DoctorMembershipsDTO = [memberships objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = DoctorMembershipsDTO;
        return cell;
    }
}

@end
```

But when I created an Object of `MembershipsView` in `HeaderCell` Class, the set rowdelegate = object of MembershipsView. Then method is getting called 
Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not clear. What you want, where is your TableViewRowProtocol delegate method? If you assigning TableViewRowProtocol delegate to Membership class, then you need to define that delegate method in Membership itself. May be you are doing in opposite manner.

Comment: I have defined rowdelegate in "HeaderCell" class because i want the method "addrow" to be called when a button ("add") on custom cell is clicked.But I wanted the implementation of the method in "MembershipsView" class. 
Please check the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign delegate after you initialize your HeaderCell.

```
ObjHeaderCell = (HeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
if (ObjHeaderCell == nil)
{
     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderCell"   owner:self options:nil];
     ObjHeaderCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
ObjHeaderCell.rowdelegate=self;
```

Comment: I actualy tried it. Then delegate is set but method is not getting called.
In debug [delegate method], just gets skipped.

Comment: try to check is rowdelegate == nil before you call it.

Comment: Exactly, thats the issue.
I don't know why it is nil.

Comment: What you exactly want to do ? Also from where add: method is called ?

Comment: Ok, i want to add a custom tableviewcell of "HeaderCell" Class (which contains an add button) in tableview of "MembershipsView" Class.
After that i want to add a cell(not of "HeaderCell" class) to tableview,when "add" button on custom cell (HeaderCell) is clicked .

Comment: I wish to use HeaderCell in tables in other classes also, so I'm setting the protocol from MembershipsView.Else I would have created an object of MembershipsView in HeaderCell and set the rowdelegate.

If there is any better method , please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Better you can `IBOutlet` your add button and add target to your button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42010/discussion-between-sreejith-virgo-and-a)